# Adding a header/description section to a dataframe Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I want to place a `header` value below the title of the data frame `data` below and get the Expected output, How would I be able to do that?

```
import pandas as pd

class SubclassedDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    # normal properties
    _metadata = ['description']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubclassedDataFrame

data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [10, 12, 13], "c": [230, 1, 3],"d": [8, 12, 9],}

df = SubclassedDataFrame(data)
title = 'Outputs'
header = 'header'

df = df.style.set_caption(title).set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'caption',
    'props': [
        ('color', 'red'),
        ('font-size', '15px'),
        ('font-style', 'italic'),
        ('font-weight', 'bold'),
        ('text-align', 'center')
    ]
}])

display(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

```
  header
```

[image]

Comment: where is display function mentioned? and what sort of IDE you are using for this? Is this code written in jupyter notebook??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 approaches:

One approach is to create a MultiIndex with header being the top level:

```
title = 'Outputs'
header = 'header'

# Add MultiIndex Header
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[header], df.columns])
styler = df.style.set_caption(title).set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'caption',
    'props': [
        ('color', 'red'),
        ('font-size', '15px'),
        ('font-style', 'italic'),
        ('font-weight', 'bold'),
        ('text-align', 'center')
    ]
}])

display(styler)
```

[image: Header as MultiIndex]

This approach keeps the integrity of the pandas Styler object, and makes "header" a part of the `table` object, being the first row in `thead`.

---

The second approach is to create a [Subclass](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Subclassing) of the Styler object and modify the `jinja` templates.

`templates/myhtml.tpl`:

```html
{% extends "html_table.tpl" %}
{% block table %}
<div class="wrap">
    {% if table_title %}
    <h1 class="table-title">{{ table_title}}</h1>
    {% endif %}
    {% if table_header %}
    <h2 class="table-header">{{ table_header }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
{{ super() }}
</div>
{% endblock table %}
```

`templates/mystyles.tpl`:

```html
{% extends "html_style.tpl" %}
{% block style %}
{{ super() }}
<style>
    .wrap {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .table-title {
        color: red;
        font-size: 15px !important;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 2px !important;
    }

    .table-header {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 13px !important;
        margin: 0 2px !important;
    }
</style>
{% endblock style %}
```

```
title = 'Outputs'
header = 'header'

# Build Styler Subclass from templates
MyStyler = Styler.from_custom_template(
    "templates",               # Folder to Search
    html_table="myhtml.tpl",   # HTML Template
    html_style='mystyles.tpl'  # CSS Template
)
# Get Styler For `df`
styler = MyStyler(df)
# Render with arguments and display
HTML(styler.render(table_title=title, table_header=header))
```

[image: Styled table with h1 and h2 elements]

This approach moves some of the control away from the Styler object to the templates, but allows significantly more flexibility as it can be used to create additional HTML elements which is currently not supported by the Styler object.

---

Environment jupyter-notebook

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML, display
from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler


class SubclassedDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    # normal properties
    _metadata = ['description']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubclassedDataFrame


data = {
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [10, 12, 13],
    "c": [230, 1, 3],
    "d": [8, 12, 9]
}

df = SubclassedDataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I created a folder named templates put the code for html.tpl and mystyles.tpl `templates\myhtml.tpl`  and  `templates\mystyles.tpl` . templates folder is allocated within the same directory as my main code but this code is till giving me an error `TypeError: from_custom_template() got an unexpected keyword argument 'html_table'`

Comment: [Styler.from_custom_template](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.from_custom_template.html) was changed in `pandas 1.3.0`. This answer was written in 1.3.3. You'll either need to adapt this code to your version, or try upgrading.